# The basic or the main component

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary

I want to write a scientific paper and I am looking for a nice word that can describe a theory can be a *basic component* or a *main tool* for another theory. What is the best word that I can use?

Comment: Generally theories are based on assumptions! What do you mean by basic component/main tool? Sort of 'established evidence'?

Comment: @Josh61 One theory can not be an evidence for another in my opinion but can be like a pillar for another one.

Comment: Fundament:an underlying theoretical basis or principle. Foundation/base : the basis on which a thing stands, is founded, or is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one or more of the following words/compound words will suffice:

**essential component**

**fundamental part**

**stepping stone**

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps 'subtheory' 'praxis' 'scaffolding' ...

Comment: Single word request answers need to be more than just a list of words. The most helpful of this type of answer gives a rationale and examples for the choices.